# Allow websocket connection only from one URL

Tags: node.js, websocket

My websocket application accepting connections like this:

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log(request);
    if(request.origin == "https://www.my-domain.com"){

        var connection  =   request.accept(null, request.origin);

         /* some lines of code
            ...
         */

    } else {
        //here I want block request
    }
```

Is here some function like `.decline()`? or `.notAccept()` or...?
When I trying connect to my websocket from different URL, my status is "pending" for a long time.
[image]

Comment: why don't just send an error msg and close the connection serverside?

Comment: According to [rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455) you are supposed to respond with an appropriate HTTP error status on handshake. If your library doesn't support it then you can always close the connection.

Comment: @Sirko connection is not established because `.accept()` is in `if`. I cant close connection if not exists.. or I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shown [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket#server-example):

```
wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
  if (! originIsAllowed(request.origin)) {
    // Make sure we only accept requests from an allowed origin 
    request.reject();
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + ' rejected.');
    return;
  }
  ...
});
```

You'd have to replace `originIsAllowed(request.origin)` with your own check.